# enter data in a column into an array

Tags: excel, vba

Need to enter a column of data into an array, i.e., A1:A4 is 1,2,3,4  and trying to enter into an array called "numbers"  is there an efficient way, or do I need to use a for-next loop and assign each to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 2-D array; e.g. numbers(1 to 4, 1 to 1)

```
dim numbers as variant
numbers = range("a1:a4").value
```

For a 1-D array from rows; e.g. numbers(0 to 3)

```
dim numbers as variant
numbers = application.transpose(range("a1:a4").value)
```

For a 1-D array from columns; e.g. numbers(0 to 3)

```
dim numbers as variant
numbers = application.transpose(application.transpose(range("a1:d1").value))
```